# Emulate Photoshop's "Color Overlay" using CSS filters?

Tags: css, image-manipulation, hsv, color-space, css-filters

I have an icon which I'd like to change the color of, using CSS. It is in a data-uri'd optimized SVG inlined in the CSS.

Normally, this *wasn't* possible. That's why icon fonts were invented; their main advantage over SVG is being able to recieve `color` and `text-shadow` rules from CSS. Well, [CSS filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) are now capable of doing both things to arbitrary images, and [they now work in all Blink, Webkit and Gecko browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), and [can be expected for future IE/Spartan](https://status.modern.ie/filters).

A `text-shadow` replacement is easy; just use the [`drop-shadow` filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#drop-shadow()).

Coloring the image into a specific color, however, has proven very tricky, despite all the necessary filters being here. My theory, up until now, is as follows:

- Use [`contrast(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#contrast()) to turn the entire image into solid grey, while keeping the alpha channel (the Mozilla wiki says it'd become black, but in all browsers it becomes grey, must be a typo).
- Use [`sepia(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#sepia()), because we cannot operate on hue/saturation on a grey image. This ensures the entire image is composed of a reference color we can do math on; specifically, `#AC9977`.

At this point, we should be able to turn the entire image from what is now solid `#AC9977` to any color we want using [`hue-rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate()), [`saturate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#saturate()) and [`brightness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#brightness()).

First, what color coordinates are browsers using? I could not find make sense of [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/filters/) to be sure if it's using [HSL (*Lightness*) or HSV (*Value*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), but since HSB (*Brightness*) is another name for HSV, I suppose it's using HSV. Furthermore, using something like `brightness(999)` saturates colors (instead of making them white), which would happen in HSV but not HSL.

Based on this assumption, we would proceed as follows:

- Calculate the hue difference between `#AC9977` and the color we want, and use [`hue-rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#hue-rotate()).
- Calculate the saturation difference between both, and use [`saturate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#saturate()).
- Calculate the brightness difference between both, and use [`brightness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#brightness()).

Since this is not the kind of stuff to be done by hand, we'll use the [LESS preprocessor](http://lesscss.org/):

```
.colorize(@color) {
    @sepiaGrey: #AC9977;
    @hOffset: (hsvhue(@color) - hsvhue(@sepiaGrey)) * 1deg;
    @sRatio: unit(hsvsaturation(@color) / hsvsaturation(@sepiaGrey));
    @vRatio: unit(hsvvalue(@color) / hsvvalue(@sepiaGrey));
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(@hOffset) saturate(@sRatio) brightness(@vRatio);
    filter: contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(@hOffset) saturate(@sRatio) brightness(@vRatio);
}
```

This, in my understanding, should work. [But it isn't](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emaJjW). *Why, and how to make it work?*

### Example of what I'm trying to achieve

Consider an icon as an image or an element (background-image, CSS-based shape, etc), with *any* color, and with a shape defined by transparency (*not* a rectangular image that could be simply overlaid). I want to make it be entirely composed of a specific color with CSS (presumably, with the use of `filters`).

[image: example]

I plan to implement this as a [LESS mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) that takes a color argument, but just guidance on the logic behind the HSB functions is enough.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve. What exactly do you mean by *fill with a solid  color*? Could you make a mock-up in Photoshop or the like of what the result should look like?

Comment: PS leaving out the brightness seems to provide a solid color as a result, I'm not sure why either but it seems to go more in the direction that you want.

Comment: @BramVanroy Consider the images in the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emaJjW). What I want is for them to only be composed of a specific color (in the example, `#729FCF`), while keeping the alpha channel. For example, consider an icon represented in SVG, which is originally white, and you want it to become some shade of red or green for different cases. I can more or less "eyeball" the color, to an extent, but I'm trying to make something that can be reused and doesn't need guesswork, and in my rudimentary understanding of colors, I've made an algorithm that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @BramVanroy example added.

Answer (score 3):

I have sometimes tried to achieve what you want, and haven't succeded.

You have anyway an alternative, using blend modes:

```css
div {
    background-color: green;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Hsl-hsv_models.svg/400px-Hsl-hsv_models.svg.png" height="400">
```

I miss the transparency requirement. Let's try again :-). Drawback: you need to set the image 2 times.

```css
#test1 {
  background: linear-gradient(red, red), url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-blend-mode: hue;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");
}

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test1">
</div>
```

Ok; let's say that the wanted result is: you have an image, that will act as a mask. You want to use this mask to set a colored overlay over an existing image, but you want the color to be specified in the CSS styles, so that it is easily editable.

If it is ok for you to change the images, so that the channel to be used is luminosity instead of alpha, the following example can be your solution
you need an filter with gray and black colors , like this

[image: mask file]

```css
.test {
        width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxKXy.png); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-blend-mode: exclusion;
    mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
}

.testred {
    background-color: red;
}

.testblue {
    background-color: blue;
}

body {
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, lightblue 0px, lightyellow 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test testred"></div>
<div class="test testblue"></div>
```

Comment: The example you're showing tints an image (and is pretty cool on its own; didn't know about `mix-blend-mode`), but it seems to be only part of the solution (making a whole icon into *just one* specific color), and as far as I can see it wouldn't work for images with transparency (it would tint whatever was behind them too).

Comment: I see your edit. Kinda sad that it only works on webkit, as it is neat. However, a bigger problem is that if you consider the example I've given, the result for `red` would be [something like this](http://i.imgur.com/qXF6sQB.png) - think of the "color overlay" from Photoshop.

Comment: That looks promising! However, the result is drastically different from what a "Color Overlay" effect looks like, [see what I mean](http://i.imgur.com/4eLVHCe.png). But all in all, this may be a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Changed example, now using a black/gray filter, and other blending modes

Comment: Congratulations. This is indeed a solution that results in the desired visual output, and certainly deserving of upvotes, despite the constraints it causes (one now needs to edit every image file server-side, and it cannot degrade gracefully without multiple images, in which case an extra image pre-colored could also have worked). Due to these constraints I cannot accept the answer in its current form, although I'm surprised by the work you've done there. I've tried combining it with css filters (to produce the "black on grey" image), but it seems they and their wierd math kick in after blend.

Comment: I am aware that this is far from production-ready code. I was just trying to explore the posibilities to get the expected result.  A real pity the masking isn't getting wider support.  Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, really. I'm kinda stubborn so I'll keep hammering on and hopefully figure out why hue-rotate was coded by the devil himself - just the HSB filters *should* be enough and eventually I may solve it and post an answer. Either way, your solution was pretty helpful for me to figure out now we can use blending modes! [See what I can do with screen and a couple gradients](http://jsfiddle.net/Camilo/h7tkb2ud/).

Comment: This is a superb answer that gave me a way to extend FontAwesome with transparent PNG images of images that aren't in FontAwesome yet. I'm still tweaking it, but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have made some progress on the maths but they're not pretty; ideally I believe any color could be represented at most in the following CSS filters:

```
(-webkit-)filter: contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(X) saturate(Y) brightness(Z);
```

In other words, ideally we should be able to express any color as hue, saturation and brightness coordinates relative to sepia grey (`#AC9977`).

While I still didn't find a way to do that (nor am sure it's possible), I managed to make an implementation that accepts any shade of pure colors (R, G, B, C, M, Y) or any neutral color (white, black, and greys). A few are optimized (like black is just `brightness(0)`). Additionally, if the color you specify has transparency, that transparency will be added as an `opacity` filter.

This is the code thus far (written in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)):

```
// Filter prefixer.
.filter(@filters) { -webkit-filter+_: @filters; filter+_: @filters; }

// Helper that conditionally adds opacity filter when color calls for it.
._conditional-opacity(@color) when (alpha(@color) < 1) {
  .filter(round(opacity(alpha(@color)), 3));
}

// Helper that adds a brightness filter when necessary.
._conditional-brightness(@channel) when (@channel < 255) {
  .filter(brightness(round(@channel / 255, 3)));
}

// Special case for pure black.
.colorize(@color) when (fade(@color, 100%) = #000) {
  .filter(brightness(0));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for pure grey and off-by-one-grey.
.colorize(@color) when (fade(@color, 100%) = #7F7F7F),
                       (fade(@color, 100%) = #808080) {
  .filter(contrast(0));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure red.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) > 0)
                   and (green(@color) = 0)
                   and (blue(@color) = 0) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) saturate(999));
  ._conditional-brightness(red(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure green.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) = 0)
                   and (green(@color) > 0)
                   and (blue(@color) = 0) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(99deg) saturate(999));
  ._conditional-brightness(green(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure blue.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) = 0)
                   and (green(@color) = 0)
                   and (blue(@color) > 0) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(199deg) saturate(999));
  ._conditional-brightness(blue(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure cyan.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) = 0)
                   and (green(@color) > 0)
                   and (blue(@color) = green(@color)) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) invert(1) saturate(999));
  ._conditional-brightness(blue(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure magenta.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) = blue(@color))
                   and (green(@color) = 0)
                   and (blue(@color) > 0) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(-99deg) saturate(999));
  ._conditional-brightness(red(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure yellow.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) > 0)
                   and (green(@color) = red(@color))
                   and (blue(@color) = 0) {
  .filter(contrast(0) sepia(1) hue-rotate(199deg) saturate(999) invert(1));
  ._conditional-brightness(green(@color));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

// Special case for shades of pure grey and white.
.colorize(@color) when (red(@color) = green(@color))
                   and (green(@color) = blue(@color))
                   and not (blue(@color) = 0) // We've optimized these before.
                   and not (blue(@color) = 127)
                   and not (blue(@color) = 128) {
  .filter(contrast(0) brightness(round(blue(@color) / 255 * 2 + .00765, 3)));
  ._conditional-opacity(@color);
}

.colorize(@color) when (default()) {
  // General case not figured out yet.
}
```

If you want to play with it, [here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwXooV) (it auto-compiles LESS).

Note that this is not good enough, and if you post an answer which is better (including using a different method to solve the problem), I may accept yours, and will not accept my own unless it can represent any given color (which it currently can't; and I may have given up on it for now).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an SVG filter referenced through a CSS filter to get close to this. It is not a true overlay blend - that requires blend-mode. But I think it actually gets you what you want. Please be aware that hue-rotation in filters is basically broken - it's only an approximation in RGB space which gets saturated colors VERY wrong. (It's actually using the original SVG Filter math under the covers).

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
<defs>
  <filter id="fakeOverlay">
    <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" result="L2A"/>
    <feFlood flood-color="cyan" result="colorfield"/>
    <feBlend mode="multiply" in="L2A" in2="colorfield"/>
    <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  </filter>
  </defs>
<image filter="url(#fakeOverlay)" width="800" height="400" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mboab.png"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Is this doable without converting images into SVGs with hard-coded colors in the markup of the page?

Comment: There are two ways of doing this without converting your source images into SVG's themselves 1) with inline svg and have your image element reference an external png - as I've done above or 2) reference this svg filter via a css filter (-webkit-filter etc.) syntax. The former will work in all recent browsers and IE10 and above, the latter will only work in browsers that support css filters.

Comment: Well, the whole point is to do this in a way that's more convenient and/or more elegant than hardcoding extra markup into the HTML (these SVG elements would need updating every time I want another color, too). I appreciate the effort, but my original motivation was to find a way to make these stylistic problems go back into the stylesheet and stay there. I wouldn't even mind putting an SVG as a `data:` into the CSS just for the filter, but it doesn't seem to be interpreted as when you use an URL.

Comment: Well you can have a separate SVG file with just the filter definitions in it. I think you're overconstraining your problem. I don't know exact use case, but just being able to do this dynamically cross browser is a huge win vs. doing this in Photoshop.

Comment: Dynamically is good, but what I'm saying is, if I have to make another request or change the markup to add styling helpers, it beats the purpose of not just adding another data:uri'd (svg) image to the CSS (and skipping extra requests/markup modifications). It can't be just a tech demo solution.

Comment: The average production web page has 120 requests - I would relax that requirement

Comment: God forbid, 120 requests? That's only acceptable in a streaming video site or something. For a normal website, you can combine all CSS, combine all javascript, and put most images (except avatars, thumbnails and the like) in the CSS as data-uris, cache CSS and JS for forever plus one day, and the client won't even need to 304 them. This makes anything blazing fast in my experience. The only extra requests later are loaded while the page renders. 120 requests is absolute madness and will load like shit on mobile.

Comment: http://www.keynote.com/performance-indexes/mobile-retail-us (it's actually 96 requests average) I ain't saying it's right - I'm saying it's what's out there.

Comment: Hello I know this is an old answer but I copied your code differently into a css file and it is overlaying the image but the color is black and not cyan. Is it possible to specify other values in flood-color in this solution? Here is a gist of my attempt that only overlays black https://gist.github.com/Modicrumb/c7eff02ff79bc19ad42c6890c73426f8.

Comment: Ask a new question tagged svg-filters with a complete working example showing how it's breaking for you and i'll take a crack at it.

Comment: I've asked a new question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573919/flood-color-not-respected-on-certain-image